# Limiting the soIving time using PySCIPOpt (SCIP ILP optimization for Python)

Tags: python, scip

I am using PySCIPOpt which is a Python library for the SCIP ILP solver. I would like to limit the optimization time. I found in the SCIP documentation that this can be done using `SCIPsetRealParam(scip, "limits/time", 600)`.

But how can this be done from the PySCIPOpt Python interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
m = pyscipopt.Model()
m.setParam('limits/time', 600)
```